# Mutually link three cells --> infinite loop?

Tags: excel, vba, infinite-loop

I am linking multiple cells in two-ways, meaning that if I change one, the other will update and viceversa. 
This code works perfectly for two cells

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$4" Then
        'Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sht_input.Range("E4").Value = Sht_input.Range("B4").Value
        'Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$E$4" Then
        'Application.EnableEvents = False
         Sht_input.Range("b4").Value = Sht_input.Range("e4").Value
        'Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
 End Sub
```

Now, when I trying to link three cells, the code goes into infinitive loop

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$4" Then
        'Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sht_input.Range("E4").Value = Sht_input.Range("B4").Value
        Sht_input.Range("h4").Value = Sht_input.Range("B4").Value
        'Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$E$4" Then
        'Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sht_input.Range("b4").Value = Sht_input.Range("e4").Value
        Sht_input.Range("h4").Value = Sht_input.Range("e4").Value
        'Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$H$4" Then
        'Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sht_input.Range("b4").Value = Sht_input.Range("H4").Value
        Sht_input.Range("e4").Value = Sht_input.Range("H4").Value
        'Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried to debug, but I cannot understand why it goes back into the "if" even if the target cells are not selected anymore. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the events. Otherwise it will always run into infinite loop that cell value is being changed. It doesn't matter if it is the same value.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Address = "$B$4" Then
    Sht_input.Range("E4").Value = Sht_input.Range("B4").Value
    Sht_input.Range("h4").Value = Sht_input.Range("B4").Value
End If

If Target.Address = "$E$4" Then

    Sht_input.Range("b4").Value = Sht_input.Range("e4").Value
    Sht_input.Range("h4").Value = Sht_input.Range("e4").Value

End If

If Target.Address = "$H$4" Then
    Sht_input.Range("b4").Value = Sht_input.Range("H4").Value
    Sht_input.Range("e4").Value = Sht_input.Range("H4").Value
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Note the changes made at the beginning as well as at the end of the code.

Comment: Shrivallabha: How was the Run Code snippet button and the other button added please?

Comment: QHarr: I have removed wrong Tags from the code snippet. It is VBA.

Comment: And i thought i had uncovered some new marvel :-)

Comment: @QHarr If you click on the Code Button while answering then a new form opens where you can paste your code. That then automatically adds the button besides wrapping the code. I am new to this site so you may expect few goof ups like these from me ;)